# Get HREF from unspecified anchor tag

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, dom-events

I have a list of auto-generated anchor tags from my code-behind which HREFs are a combination of # and the ID from an object extracted from a database.

What I need to do is to get the HREF using Javascript and put in to a function.

```
function someFunction(hrefValue){
    // Run some functionallity here
}
```

I imagine that I have to, in my code-behind, add an onclick to my auto-generated anchor tags:

```
Controls.Add(new LitarelControl("<a href='#"+ item.ID+"' onclick='someFunction();'>Hi</a>");
```

A friend of mine told me that I **HAVE** to specify which anchor tag's HREF I want, but as all of my anchor tags in my custom control runs the same Javascript, I can't specify one single HREF.

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do pass `this` as parameter into `someFunction();`.

```
function someFunction(anchor){
    alert(anchor.getAttribute('href'));
}
```

**Demo**: http://www.jsfiddle.net/5HXK2/

Answer (score 1):

You could modify the function (and the call) to pass in the object:

```
function someFunction(sender){     
   // get href from sender object
} 

Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<a href='#"+ item.ID+"' 
        onclick='someFunction(this);'>Hi</a>");
```